# I need to push small Idea adjusted project *.iml and other files once

Tags: git

I need to push small Idea adjusted project *.iml and other files once, but they are in gitignore. Is there way to push without gitignore check? I can not change gitignore cause there are big repo with many sub-projects and many users are connected.

Comment: Remove it from gitignore

Comment: Why do you want to push them ? Do you want to share them with someone ? Probably it still shouldn't be in your repo, it's not part of the source. Send it over email or ftp

Comment: This is example how to use and adjust new library. So project is part of source now.

Answer (score 1):

If these particular files are going to remain in the project, you should exclude them explicitly from your gitignore rules, like so:

```
*.iml    #Exclude all iml
!/path/to/your/example.iml #Except this one
```

Comment: It works, but i need hole subfolder to skip all gitignore rules like : !folder/Android_adjust_example/

Comment: Cause there are near 10 files ignored to push now.